# Header is not created in Excel using Apache POI Java

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I wrote code the below to create a header in the excel file. But the header is always giving empty. Can you please correct me, if am wrong in the code.

```
XSSFRow row=spreadsheet.createRow(1);
              XSSFCell cell;

              cell=row.createCell(1);
              cell.setCellValue("ID");
              cell=row.createCell(2);
              cell.setCellValue("area_info_id");
```

Comment: Create it as the first row, which is row 0?

Comment: Perfect. working. Thank yo Gagravarr

Answer (score 2):

Use the header related function to set your header.

```
Header header = spreadsheet.getHeader();
header.setLeft("Left");
header.setCenter("Center");
header.setRight("Right");
```